# Cannot resolve method contains(int, int)?

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to check particular region contains touch points on `onTouchEvent` in Android. Initially I put my all the regions data in array as follows.

```
ArrayList<Region> regionlist = new ArrayList<>();

RectF rectF = new RectF();
path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
r = new Region();
r.setPath(path, new Region((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom));
regionlist.add(r);
```

Here is my `onTouchEvent`.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = (int) event.getX();
    point.y = (int) event.getY();
    invalidate();
    Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);


    for( Object result : regionlist ) {
        Log.d("isuru", "Bucha " + result);
        if(result.contains(point.x, point.y)) { //Error Line
            Log.d(TAG, "Touch IN");
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Touch OUT");
        }

    }
    return true;

}
```

As I mention in my code `contains` shows error as `Cannot resolve method contains(int, int)`? Why this happens?

Comment: You need to use the correct type for `result` -- `for( Region result : regionlist )`.

Comment: `result` is of type `Object` and `Object` does not have a method `contains(int,int)` check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html?is-external=true), you need to use to correct type!

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the following code

```
for( Object result : regionlist ) {
 //code
}
```

to

```
for( Region result : regionlist ) {
 //code
}
```